How to combine background blur and normal filter blur?
So ok, dont get me wrong i tried this so many times in different ways to do it, I even tried SVG Gussain Blurs. I Just cant combine those two effects.
So basically i want to make a navigation bar similar to the one i created on Figma like the image Shown, Fancy Nav Bar Using Figma.

I think what you're looking for is a gradient backdrop filter. mask can achieve the gradient effect of the backdrop filter:
<article>
  <header class="fixed inset-x-0 top-0 z-10 h-96 bg-gradient-to-b from-black/50 to-transparent">
    <!-- -webkit-mask for compatibility -->
    <div class="h-full backdrop-blur-xl [-webkit-mask:linear-gradient(to_bottom,black_50%,transparent)] [mask:linear-gradient(to_bottom,black_50%,transparent)]">
      <div class="py-8 text-center text-2xl font-semibold text-white">Header</div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <img class="blur-[2px]" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/firefox-logo.svg" />
  </main>
</article>

Demo on Tailwind Play.
